# Pipe compiler output into head

Tags: bash

I want to view only the top lines of the compiler output from gcc so I tried the command `gcc myfile.c | head -10` but I still see all of the output. I use the Bash shell. Thanks.

Comment: `gcc myfile.c 2>&1 | head -10`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Pipeline normally only redirects stdout, but compiler errors are outputed to stderr. You can redirect both stdout and stderr by using `|&` instead of `|`.

Comment: The tip is correct for Bash but the proper, compatible redirection operation is to use `gcc ... 2>&1 | head` to redirect both standard output and standard error to `head`.

Comment: Can syntax colouring be preserved?